# Dividing Cuboid into Equal Cubes

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the formula to divide a large cuboid into equal cubes given a starting Length, Width, Height and known quantity of cubes so that the combined volume of the cubes equals the total volume of the cuboid?

For instance, if I had a cuboid that was 24.4in X 11.6in X 8in and wanted to get 500 smaller cubes of the exact same size.

When I tried to guess at the formula, I divided each side by 500, to get 0.0488, 0.0232, 0.0160 L,W,H respectively. The volume of this cube is 0.000018 inches$^3$ while the volume of the cuboid is 2264.32 inches$^3$. Then if I multiply $0.000018*500$ I only get 0.009 which doesn't match 2264.32.

What am I missing?

Comment: When you divide each side by $500$, you divide the cuboid into $500^3=1 \,250\,000$ smaller cuboids. A Rubik's Cube may aid visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you divide the length by $m$, the width by $n$, and the height by $p$ you get $mnp$ little cuboids.  If you want to divide the large one into $500$ you need to find three numbers whose product is $500$.  One choice would be $4,5,25$ so you could make the length $\frac {24.4}{25}=0.976$ and compute the others the same way.  The small pieces will not be cubical, but they will be cuboids.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan. Based on what you said here and player3236, I was able to figure this out using this formula:

$LinearDimension / Quantity^(1/3)$ = $24.4/500^(1/3)$ = 3.0742073

On a side note, I cannot get the notation correct for this reply.

Comment: @StephenBS:  to get multicharacter superscripts enclose them in braces, so L^{(1/3)} gives $L^{(1/3)}$  It works everywhere.  You are assuming you can cut $500^{(1/3)}\approx 7.94$ cuboids in each dimension, but that doesn't work because it isn't a cube.  You could cut $8$ in each dimension if you want, giving $512$ small cuboids.